# Regex Parsing Beginning of Line

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, regex-group

I have a string and I would like to parse it using regular expression. `..` indicates the category name and everything after `:` is the content for that category.

Below is the full string I'm trying to parse:

```
..NAME: JOHN
..BDAY: 1/1/2010
..NOTE: 1. some note 1
 2. some note 2
 3. some note 3
..DATE: 6/3/2014
```

I'm trying to parse it so that

```
(group 1) 
..NAME: JOHN

(group 2)
..BDAY: 1/1/2010

(group 3)
..NOTE: 1. some note 1
 2. some note 2
 3. some note 3

(group 4)
..DATE: 6/3/2014  //a.k.a update date
```

The regular expression patter I use is

```
\.\.[A-Z0-9]{2,4}:.*
```

which makes `(group 3) ..NOTE: 1. some note 1` missing the content on second and third line.

How can I modify my pattern so I can get the correct grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` matches all but newline (in most languages, Ruby is one exception).  Use [`RegexOptions.Singleline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx#memberList) in C# (or the [`s` modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) in PCRE).

---

You will need to make your `.*` lazy up till the next `..` or the end of the string `$` so that you don't match everything the first time.  Also, `.` doesn't have any special meaning in a character class..so your expression may end up looking cleaner like this:

```
[.]{2}[A-Z0-9]{2,4}:.*?(?=[.]{2}|$)
```

**Demos:** [Regex](http://regex101.com/r/eN6vN9) and [C#](http://ideone.com/xCufyP)

Comment: Thanks! However, that still doesn't solve the issue where group 3 is only getting the first line. My goal is to get all 3 lines for group 3. Also, I'm using C#.

Comment: @sora0419 sorry! I meant `Singleline` not `Multiline`..I'm not proficient in C# and I misread the docs.  I added a [C# demo](http://ideone.com/xCufyP).

Comment: The demo definitely helped a lot! Thank you so much!

Comment: Note, that this will include trailing newlines (since `\n` is matched by `.` and occurs before the `[.]{2}` in the lookahead).  You can fix this by adding whitespace to the lookahead: `(?=\s*[.]{2}|$)`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve it with the negative lookahead for `[.]{2}`:

```
[.]{2}[A-Z0-9]{2,4}:(.*\n?(?![.]{2}))*
```